# Why can't i receive twice from the same client

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically i have client, ip = s.accept()

i want to send and receive send and receive, but printing out the second receive returns nothing

I'm connecting through Putty RAW Mode, i tried different programs but nothing worked.

```py
def function(client, ip):
        print(Fore.YELLOW + f"Connection from {ip} Established")
        client.send("Username: ".encode("utf-8"))
        username = client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        client.send("Password: ".encode("utf-8"))
        password = client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        print(username + ":" + password)
```

I expected it to output "username:password"
but it returns "username:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to just expect the first `recv` to get the username and the second `recv` to get the password by magic or luck. If there's some protocol that allows you tell where the username ends and the password begins, you need to implement it.

Your first call to `recv` might get just the first letter of the username. Maybe the first call got the username and the second call got a space or newline character between the username and the password and you haven't read the password yet. Who knows?

If there's no way to know where the boundary between the username and password is, there's no way this code can possibly work. If there is some way, what is that way and where is the code that implements it?

Is your code supposed to receive the username before you send the `Password:` prompt? If so, where's the code to do that? You call `recv`, but you don't check to see if it's the username. It could just be the first character of the username. It could be more. You need to look at it and see what it is. Do not send the `Password:` prompt until you've received the entire username. You have to actually implement whatever protocol you are using and the client has to use that same protocol.

Comment: let's assume the username is gonna be "frick" and the password is "1337" ALWAYS just elaborate how can i implement that in a functioning CNC

Comment: @user11449806 It depends on how whatever protocol you're implementing separates the username from the password., which I don't know. Is the username followed by a newline character? Or  zero byte? Whatever the client is supposed to use is what you need to test for. You should not send the `Password:` prompt until you've received the username, which you don't test for. (See updates)